# Can dd with no options other than an output file and /dev/urandom input file cause other files on the partition to be overwritten?

Tags: command-line, mount, hard-drive, usb-drive, dd

I have a USB-mounted hard drive with **7 GB** of free space that I tried to fill with pseudo-random data using these commands:

```
$ cd /media/username/volume_name
$ sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=random_data_file.txt
```

`random_data_file.txt` previously didn't exist. I expected the command to create the file, write pseudo-random data to it, and stop when the containing partition became full. The status bar of the file manager eventually displayed `0 bytes` of free space. But the `dd` command didn't stop, and neither the terminal emulator nor the file manager presented any notification that the drive was full. After I terminated the command with `Ctrl+C`, the terminal output stated **40 GB** has been written. I selected the file in the manager, whose status bar also displayed its size as **40 GB**, which is 33 GB more than the previous amount of free space.

1. Is there any chance this command has overwritten or modified some of my
   other files, the partition, or other partitions? Or does this mean
   `random_data_file.txt` has been written and overwritten 40 GB / 7 GB =
   5.7 times? If the latter, then why did the file manager display its size as greater than 7 GB? After deleting `random_data_file.txt` using the
   file manager, its status bar reverts to displaying free space as 7 GB.
2. What is the correct way to use the `dd` command to create and write
   pseudo-random data to an output file until its containing partition
   is full, without overwriting anything (other than free space on the same partition),
   including that output file?

Comment: ubfan1: none of those things are important.  Most of your comment is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your disk hardware is good (and not a fradulent SD card showing fake available space), and your filesystem isn't corrupt with corrupted freelists and files whose blocks are still in the freelist, then `dd if=/dev/urandom of=random_data_file.txt` would not corrupt the disk or overwrite anything (other than random_datafile.txt).

Likely you didn't need the sudo in front, and if you aren't sure your dd command is correct, you certainly shouldn't run it as sudo.

One possible reason why it wrote more data than you expected is that most filesystems reserve a bit of free space (typically 5%) so that root can continue writing when regular users see the disk as full.  (Again, don't do this with sudo...)

Comment: Ah, it's ext4, & 33GB is < 5%. Does reserved space apply to my partition, which is on 2nd drive, neither /boot nor /home? If so, then would dd stop when reserve is filled by dd & maybe some daemon, without overwriting daemon-written data? If only root can write in reserve, then when I as non-root deleted file via GUI, did I wholly delete file, including 33GB portion, & nothing else? After rebooting, I couldn't reach greeter until I hard-shutdown. Why? Is it possible a daemon had no space to write or dd or daemon overwrote the other's writes, & files/disk got corrupted? Can it affect boot-up?

Comment: The 5% is a guess, it can be set to anything when creating or tuning the filesystem.  Assuming your filesystem isn't corrupt, nobody overwrote anyone's files, that's the point of having a filesystem.   If the disk completely filled, some daemons may have been unable to write their log files and state files, and the system may not boot correctly until the space is freed.  Who knows what might have gone wrong if it was full.  Reserve space is specific to each filesystem and only applies when writing files.  It has nothing to do with users deleting things which should work normally.

Comment: I tested the command again, with and without `sudo`, with output file on an ext4-formatted spare thumb drive. The command eventually finishes with the terminal output of "No space left on device"—to write by that user with that user’s current privileges. The terminal output would be clearer if it included that detail. With reserved space for root, the command with `sudo` wrote more data before reaching this message.